# iPhone UIView Animation Best Practice

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation

What is considered best practice for animating view transitions on the iPhone?

For example, the `ViewTransitions` sample project from apple uses code like:

```
CATransition *applicationLoadViewIn = [CATransition animation];
[applicationLoadViewIn setDuration:1];
[applicationLoadViewIn setType:kCATransitionReveal];
[applicationLoadViewIn setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
[[myview layer] addAnimation:applicationLoadViewIn forKey:kCATransitionReveal];
```

but there are also code snippets floating around the net that look like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:myview cache:YES];
[myview removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

What is the best approach? If you could provide a snippet as well it'd be much appreciated.

**NOTE:** I've been unable to get the second approach to work correctly.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

From the [UIView reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW14)'s section about the `beginAnimations:context:` method:

> Use of this method is discouraged in iPhone OS 4.0 and later. You should use the block-based animation methods instead.

**Eg of Block-based Animation based on Tom's Comment**

```
[UIView transitionWithView:mysuperview 
                  duration:0.75
                   options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
                animations:^{ 
                    [myview removeFromSuperview]; 
                } 
                completion:nil];
```

Comment: So.. to be clear, that means use the first approach (CATransition), not the second?

Comment: Yes, it is the first approach (CATransition).

Comment: @Steven N, no, it means to use the block-based animations on `UIView` instead. They're essentially the same as `beginAnimations` and friends, but use block/closure features.

Comment: Yes, Yar is right. This is how a block animation looks like: 
`[UIView transitionWithView:mysuperview duration:0.75 options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{ [myview removeFromSuperview]; } completion:nil]` Check the UIView documentation for details.

Comment: Except if you want to support 3.1.3 phones.  Then don't use blocks.

Comment: Just curious, no intention to start a war: why the downvotes?  :)

Answer (score 69):

I have been using the latter for a lot of nice lightweight animations.  You can use it crossfade two views, or fade one in in front of another, or fade it out.  You can shoot a view over another like a banner, you can make a view stretch or shrink...  I'm getting a lot of mileage out of `beginAnimation`/`commitAnimations`.

Don't think that all you can do is:

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:myview cache:YES];
```

Here is a sample:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; {
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    if (movingViewIn) {
// after the animation is over, call afterAnimationProceedWithGame
//  to start the game
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(afterAnimationProceedWithGame)];

//      [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:5.0]; // don't forget you can repeat an animation
//      [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.50];
//      [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];

        gameView.alpha = 1.0;
        topGameView.alpha = 1.0;
        viewrect1.origin.y = selfrect.size.height - (viewrect1.size.height);
        viewrect2.origin.y = -20;

        topGameView.alpha = 1.0;
    }
    else {
    // call putBackStatusBar after animation to restore the state after this animation
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(putBackStatusBar)];
        gameView.alpha = 0.0;
        topGameView.alpha = 0.0;
    }
    [gameView setFrame:viewrect1];
    [topGameView setFrame:viewrect2];

} [UIView commitAnimations];
```

As you can see, you can play with alpha, frames, and even sizes of a view.  Play around.  You may be surprised with its capabilities.

Answer (score 52):

The difference seems to be the amount of control you need over the animation.

The `CATransition` approach gives you more control and therefore more things to set up, eg. the timing function. Being an object, you can store it for later, refactor to point all your animations at it to reduce duplicated code, etc.

The `UIView` class methods are convenience methods for common animations, but are more limited than `CATransition`. For example, there are only four possible transition types (flip left, flip right, curl up, curl down). If you wanted to do a fade in, you'd have to either dig down to `CATransition's` fade transition, or set up an explicit animation of your `UIView`'s alpha.

Note that `CATransition` on Mac OS X will let you specify an arbitrary `CoreImage` filter to use as a transition, but as it stands now you can't do this on the iPhone, which lacks `CoreImage`.

Comment: Note that this is iOS 2.0-era advice. See Rafael Vega's answer on block-based methods if you're on iOS 4.0 or up.

Comment: Also note that CoreImage is now available as of iOS 5, but only a few of its features. I believe you can use a CoreImage transition in an animation, but you can't make custom CoreImage filters on iOS (5).

Answer (score 26):

We can animate images in ios 5 using this simple code.

```
CGRect imageFrame = imageView.frame;
imageFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
    delay:1.0
    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
    animations:^{
        imageView.frame = imageFrame;
    } 
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
        NSLog(@"Done!");
    }];
```

Comment: this is available in iOS 4 as well and is referred to as a "block based" animation. It is not restricted to iOS 5 and later.

Answer (score 8):

In the `UIView` docs, have a read about this function for **ios4+**

```
+ (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

Answer (score 6):

Anyway the  "Block" method is preferred now-a-days. I will explain the simple block below.

Consider the snipped below. bug2 and bug 3 are imageViews. The below animation describes an animation with 1 second duration after a delay of 1 second. The bug3 is moved from its center to bug2's center. Once the animation is completed it will be logged "Center Animation Done!".

```
-(void)centerAnimation:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"Center animation triggered!");
CGPoint bug2Center = bug2.center;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:1.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     bug3.center = bug2Center;
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Center Animation Done!");
                 }];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is Code for Smooth animation.
[I found this snippet of code from this tutorial.](http://www.lafosca.cat/smooth-and-custom-animations-in-ios/)

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[animation setAutoreverses:YES];
[animation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.3f]];
[animation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.f]];
[animation setDuration:2.f];
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];

[animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
[[self.myView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"scale"];/// add here any Controller that you want t put Smooth animation.
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's do try and checkout For Swift 3:

```
UIView.transition(with: mysuperview, duration: 0.75, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromRight , animations: {
    myview.removeFromSuperview()
}, completion: nil)
```