# UIView animation

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I am trying to animate a `UIView` here. It looks like a rectangle, and I just want to translate it to my coordinations.

So, how can I animate it? I tried to find some tutorials, but without success.

Comment: Please Refer this link for UIView Animation
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630265/iphone-uiview-animation-best-practice

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is an example of animating a view to move off screen. You should be able to slightly adjust it for your needs:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"bucketsOff" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
//position off screen
[bucketView setCenter:CGPointMake(-160, 377)];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(finishAnimation:finished:context:)];
//animate off screen
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: No luck. I declaring the 'myView' in header file. I put it on viewDidLoad as [myView setCenter:CGPointMake(-160, 377)];

Comment: If you declare a line outside of an animation block, it will have no effect on the animation whatsoever.

Comment: This works if you put it within `viewWillAppear`. It also supports auto layout, meaning I had a box centered vertically and horizontally, but changing the center worked perfectly to animate it.

Answer (score 22):

In iOS 4, the UIView block animation method is easiest:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    myView.frame = myNewFrameRect;
}];
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:

Comment: The greatest answer ever

Answer (score 5):

```
//try this AnimationTransitionCurlDown \UP

-(void)pageDown
{
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self cache:YES];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)pageUP
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self cache:YES];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
}

//flip uiviews  using animation



-(void)FlipFromLeft
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self cache:YES];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)FlipFromRight
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self cache:YES];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use "QuartzCore.framework"
With these animations.

```
-(void)viewSlideInFromRightToLeft:(UIView *)views
{
    CATransition *transition = nil;
    transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5;//kAnimationDuration
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromRight;
    transition.delegate = self;
    [views.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
}

-(void)viewSlideInFromLeftToRight:(UIView *)views
{
    CATransition *transition = nil;
    transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5;//kAnimationDuration
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromLeft;
    transition.delegate = self;
    [views.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
}

-(void)viewSlideInFromTopToBottom:(UIView *)views
{
    CATransition *transition = nil;
    transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5;//kAnimationDuration
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromBottom ;
    transition.delegate = self;
    [views.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
}

-(void)viewSlideInFromBottomToTop:(UIView *)views
{
    CATransition *transition = nil;
    transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5;//kAnimationDuration
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromTop ;
    transition.delegate = self;
    [views.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
}
```

Comment: For AnimationSubType you can use following option:->

kCATransitionFromLeft,
kCATransitionFromRight,
kCATransitionFromTop,
kCATransitionFromBottom

Comment: For AnimationType you can use following option:-> kCATransitionMoveIn, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"your text" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4]; //Your animation duration
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
//
write your code here , what you want to animate
//
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Working Fine definitely.