# Animate UIButton when View Loads

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I have six UIButtons that I'd like to have roll into place from the right side of the screen. How can I do this?
After the animation, the screen should look like this:
[image]

Comment: Could you describe what did you try? I mean that nobody will implement project specification instead of you.

Comment: There are many many (many) resources to figure out how to animate a view. Google is your friend.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIView animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156840/uiview-animation)

Answer (score 1):

The smoothest way is to use CoreAnimation. However you could use a NSTimer and manipulate the x and y from a coordinate offscreen.

You can also use iOS's built in animation functions by manipulating the center of the button like below:

```
CGPoint locationToGo = CGPointMake( 20.0f + button1.frame.size.width / 2.0f, button1.center.y);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
button1.center = locationToGo;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```