# Animate an ImageView from the ViewController in Xcode (objective-c)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I am stuck trying to animate a UIView that I created on the Main.StoryBoard.

I created the outlet for it in my ViewController.h file.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *Player;
```

The animation I attempted was:

```
 - (void) PlayerMoves {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations: self.Player.center = CGPointMake(self.Player.center.x, self.Player.center.y -50) completion:nil]; 
}
```

Anything I do, it tells me that I have an error.

> Sending 'CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint') to parameter of incompatible type 'void (^ _Nonnull)(void)'

Comment: If I left out something that I needed to have included please let me know. Thanks in Advanced guys!

Comment: Probably want to have a look at these links: [1. UIView animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156840/uiview-animation) . [2. iPhone UIView Animation Best Practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630265/iphone-uiview-animation-best-practice) . [3. iOS Animation Tutorial: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113674/ios-animation-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: Thanks for the links and thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass **blocks** into `animateWithDuration`. An example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
    // your animation here
    self.Player.center = CGPointMake(self.Player.center.x, self.Player.center.y -50)
} completion:nil];
```

Parameter `animations` in this method is type of `(void (^)(void))`. You need to read a bit more about blocks in Objective-C and how to use them.