# iphone: change content of a view with Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview

I need help on this thing. I have 3 view controllers say Parent and Child1, Child2

in Parent viewcontollers I have a view called container and a segmented control.

Now I want that content of this 'container' view change with animation everytime the value of segmented control is changed.

I have done till here please tell me what needs to be added:

```
if (selectSearchType.selectedSegmentIndex==0) {



    [aAdvanceSearchViewContoller.view removeFromSuperview];
    [container addSubview:aBasicSearchViewController.view];

}else {
    NSLog(@"Advance Search");
    [aBasicSearchViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [container addSubview:aAdvanceSearchViewContoller.view];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following lines to your code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:myview cache:YES];
[myview removeFromSuperview]; //remove or addSubview as required
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Also check out the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630265/iphone-uiview-animation-best-practice