# Positioning A Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I position a button on my view dynamically?

Comment: Any button, or a specific button?

Comment: And do you want a pointer to the UIButton, or the location of it in the view, etc.? Be more specific in your questions.

Comment: How can i locate a button on my view dynamically? mean any button

Comment: For all I know, he's asking how to place a button at a specific coordinate at runtime somewhere on the view.

Comment: @fasttrack:true actually i need to give a animation effect so it make user seem like buttons are rotating around a point

Comment: @rptwsthi Please edit your question then, and clarify it. People are giving you answers to something you're not interested in because your question wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now we understand the question better...

You can place a button/UIComponent at runtime by settings its `frame`. This will place it at a given coordinate within the view containing the button.

```
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(newX, newY, myButton.frame.width, myButton.frame.height);
```

If you wish to do a linear style animation (no curves), look up `CATransitions`, see [iPhone UIView Animation Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630265/iphone-uiview-animation-best-practice). If you need to support pre-iOS4 devices, you can't use `CATransitions`, and have to do it the old way using `UIView` animations.

To do more complex animations, you might have to mess around with timers, which can slightly juddery effects if you're trying to do complicated animation paths.

Comment: thanks.. finally.. actually i'm very new to iPhone development thus i don't exactly know how to ask :P

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
for(UIView * view in self.view.subviews)
{
     if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
     {
          // view is button
     }
}
```

You can also use tags

Comment: Presumably he wants a specific button?

Comment: in that case, he wants a specific component from the view.subviews( no need to differentiate it as button), in that case tag will be only option. :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the `tag` property of the UIButton (e.g. in interface builder, or programatically). Then you can walk the children of the owning view:

```
for (UIView *view in myView.subviews) {
    if (view.tag == 101 /*or whatever you set it to*/) {
        // things...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a array of all the subviews of a view using:

[myView subviews]

iterate through that array and check for your butotn by some unique characteristic. (You can set the button's tag attribute to some unique value and check for that value)