# View animation on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a NSArray that contain views ,the first view of this array is loaded at start.
When the user swipe is finger to the left position I need to change the current view with the next view of the NSArray. The previous view (the starting view) need to go at the left direction and the next view need to come from the right side. How I can do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is provided as an example in Apple docs.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at mahboudz answer here [iPhone UIView Animation Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630265/iphone-uiview-animation-best-practice)