# iPhone UIAnimation using blocks not working

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewanimation

As suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3441327/443292)  popular answer, I am using blocks for animating views as per the code:

```
UIView *whiteout = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
whiteout.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:whiteout];
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{ [whiteout removeFromSuperview]; } completion:nil];
```

However the animation does not happen and the **whiteout** view is removed immediately. What am i missing here??

Answer (score 3):

Removing from a superview is not animatable. If you want to fade out your view, try setting its alpha to 0, then remove it on completion:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{
    whiteout.alpha = 0.0;
} completion:^(BOOL completion){
    [whiteout removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

Comment: Thanx.. The fading effect works nice. But how can I add the flip transition effect??

Comment: For a flip, you'll need a CATransform3D.

Comment: Then what does the option para "UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight" does?